# React native use a local font on snack.expo.io

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, expo

How can I use a local font on snack.expo.io?

I have a ttf font, which I would like to use as evidence on snack.expo.io, but I do not quite understand how I could do it.

Some advice?

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating your snack you can import files. You can see beside **Project** there are three vertical dots, click that takes you to the import menu.

[image: Where to import files on expo]

Selecting `Import files` will take you to this screen where you can either browse or drag and drop your files. I prefer to drag and drop.

[image: import window]

You can then drag the files to the folder that you wish them to be located in.

Then to use your custom font you can follow the guide in the documentation.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/

Here is a quick code example.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants, Font } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files


export default class App extends React.Component {
  // <- use the button on the left, three vertical dots to import files

  // set the initial state
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // load fonts
    await this.loadFonts();
  }

  loadFonts = async () => {
    // load the font 
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
  }

  render() {
    // use the font in your text components
    // only render the Text component when the font has been loaded.
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.fontLoaded ? (<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold', fontSize: 56 }}>
          Hello, world!
        </Text>) : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

And an accompanying snack to show it working, notice I have stored my fonts in the folder `./assets/fonts/` https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/custom-font

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried how you say: https://snack.expo.io/BJlFp_4N4
But it does not seem to work very well, especially with Android and the font is not loaded immediately, I have not loaded completely.

Is there another way?
For example without using: import {Font} from 'expo'; ?

Comment: This is the only way, as far as I know, that you can load an external font in Expo. If font is not loaded immediately you can use `state` to control the rendering of your `Text` component. I have updated the snack and the code example to use the `state` method that Expo suggests.

Comment: I did as you say, but on android my example does not seem to work?

Try it yourself.
Link: https://snack.expo.io/S1u8MGr44

Since I need a module, I would not use "Font" of "expo" as it is a heavy module.
  how can I do if I wanted to do the same thing but without it, do we put a react-native project in place without expo?

I was talking about snack.expo.io, because I use it for testing online without having to create a project and it's easy to share with others.

Comment: The version on Android is not loaded by me.

Comment: I think there may be an issue with your font on Android. It may not be compatible.